# Send Variation options to stripe as metadata with WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, stripe-payments, product-variations

I am using this code to send product data to stripe as metadata.

```
function filter_wc_stripe_payment_metadata( $metadata, $order, $source ) {

    $count = 1;

    foreach( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $line_item ){
        $item_data = $line_item->get_data();
        $product = $line_item->get_product();
        $location = $product->get_attribute('location');
        $product_name = $product->get_name();
        $item_quantity = $line_item->get_quantity();
        $item_total = $line_item->get_total();
        $metadata['Item '.$count] = '';
        $count += 1;
    }

    return $metadata;
}

add_filter( 'wc_stripe_payment_metadata', 'filter_wc_stripe_payment_metadata', 10, 3 );
```

How can I get the selected variation of the product and add it to the metadata?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$attribute = $product->get_attribute('location');` didn't work for me for some reason. So I used this which works well so far.

```
foreach ( $item->get_formatted_meta_data() as $meta_id => $meta ) {
    $value = $args['autop'] ? wp_kses_post( $meta->display_value ) : wp_kses_post( make_clickable( trim( $meta->display_value ) ) );
    $strings[] = $value;
}

$attribute = $strings[1];
$attribute = str_ireplace('<p>','',$attribute);
$attribute = str_ireplace('</p>','',$attribute);  

$metadata['Location'] = $attribute;
```